# Search config file stanzas for missing value

Tags: python, config

I have many configuration files containing many stanzas. I would like to search each stanza for a missing key value pair and insert to the end of each stanza. The configuration files can contain 1 or 1000 stanzas depending on the file.
The configuration files look like this:

```
[stanza name]
key = value
key2 = value
...

[another stanza]
setting = value
setting2 = value
...
```

For each of the stanzas, if `key_something` does not exist, append to bottom of stanza.

As a nice to have, an option to filter the stanza for `key_something_else = value_something_else` and append the same missing key value pair, that would be awesome

I am not even sure where to start. Attempted to google an answer but I am either not searching the correct terms or there is not an example I can find. Unfortunately I do not know what I do not know.
Expected output would look like:

```
#good stanza
[stanza name]
key = value
key2 = value
requiredKey = requiredValue
key_something_else = value_something_else

# stanza missing "requiredKey = requiredValue". Need to append "requiredKey = requiredValue" to stanza
[another stanza]
setting = value
setting2 = value

#stanza missing "requiredKey = requiredValue" but does contain "key_something_else = value_something_else". Need to append "requiredKey = requiredValue". (The purpose of "key_something_else = value_something_else" is so I can build on it as time goes by)
[third stanza]
key = value
key2 = value
key_something_else = value_something_else
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this problem is to use a Python script to parse through the configuration files and look for the missing key-value pair in each stanza. You can use the built-in `configparser` module to read and write the configuration files and use regular expressions to search for the key-value pair.

```
import configparser
import re

required_key = 'requiredKey'
required_value = 'requiredValue'

optional_key = 'key_something_else'
optional_value = 'value_something_else'

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read(['file1.cfg', 'file2.cfg', ...])

for section in config.sections():
    if not config.has_option(section, required_key):
        config.set(section, required_key, required_value)
    elif config.has_option(section, optional_key) and config.get(section, optional_key) == optional_value:
        config.set(section, required_key, required_value)

with open('file1.cfg', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)

with open('file2.cfg', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```